# Xcode 4.0 beachball and freeze on app run

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, gdb

Hope someone can assist me with their expertise...i am having a problem with Xcode freezing on app RUN. The problem is intermittent.

When i run the app, the console shows the following output:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1518) (Sat Feb 12 02:56:02 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".2#b2a16f854957b341^2@43"Xcode.IDEFoundation.ConsoleAdaptor.Debugger17"tty /dev/ttys000
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
(gdb)
```

At which point, Xcode freezes with the beachball of death and only way is Force Quit it and re-launch.  Device (iphone 4) remains with a black screen, however responsive to home button.
Activity manager shows 100% CPU on Xcode while it's frozen.

Steps i have tried:
- reinstall Xcode (complete uninstall + fresh install)
- restore device (complete restore erasing all data and settings)
- Reinstalled OS X

Some more observations:
- with GDB ON, "wait for app to launch" seems to solve the issue temporarily
- after comitting to repository, app launches properly once, then goes back to freezing on next run
- option+clicking on functions or classes (quick help) freezes Xcode as well, however when it works, i know the app will launch fine with GDB on. This is possibly very important piece of info.

The only workaround that I have found is turning off GDB in the Edit Scheme Window. This way it works 100%. But obviously, without debugger...which is what i really need at this point.

The same issue has been reported on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665909/why-does-gdb-debugger-constantly-freeze-xcode-4/), however the thread has been without any movement for quite a while, and i decided to open another one. 
Some pointed out to get a process sample when it's frozen - i am ready to do anything to solve this issue at this point, just need someone with more in-depth knowledge of the system to help me out.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Reinstalled OS X, after 2-3 runs, same beachball on GDB... the problem is with the project itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem has disappeared after witching to Lion and latest Xcode version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and solved it by removing all breakpoints I'd defined. I've no idea why this caused GDB to stall, but it did.

That said, I've continued to experience beach balls in XCode 4.0.x for other, unknown reasons as well. I can't remember it happening on the XCode betas though.